# SQL Server Service Broker Receive and WaitFor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, service-broker

I am looking at a new application and using SQL Server's Service Broker seems to be a good fit for it. I'm very experienced with SQL Server, but brand new to Service Broker. I am looking at using a queue with an Internal Activation stored procedure, as found here ([Creating an Internal Activation Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/service-broker/lesson-2-creating-an-internal-activation-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15))

From my understanding and experimentation, once a message hit the queue, the stored procedure is called, but why do a number of examples then use WAITFOR ... TIMEOUT? What would I be waiting for if this is an activation procedure? Wouldn't the message be in the queue already waiting to be received?

Comment: The procedure is activated when there are messages, but you might wanna keep it going if there are any new messages in the queue after activation started. This is why it's usually looped in the examples. After activation, you want to keep going until some sort of timeout